Solving linear system of equations with constraints on unknowns
I would like to solve a system of linear equations $y=Uh$ for an unknown vector $h$, where I have a few constraints on some of the elements of $h$. The matrix $U$ is composed of a vector $u$ (length $N$) and delayed versions of it.
Let us consider a small example: $y$ is a vector of size $N$ corrupted by measurement noise, $U$ is a matrix of size $N \times 9$, where:
the 1st column of $U$ is the vector $u$;
the 2nd column is one time step delayed vector u i.e. [0; u(1:end-1)];
the 3rd column is two time step delayed vector u i.e. [0; 0; u(1:end-2)];
the 4th column is a square of individual elements of 1st column;
the 5th column is a square of individual elements of 2nd column;
the 6th column is a square of individual elements of the 3rd column;
the 7th column is the product of individual elements of columns 1 and 2;
the 8th column is the product of individual elements of columns 1 and 3;
the 9th column is the product of individual elements of columns 2 and 3;
and $h$ is a vector of size $9$, where $N>9$. Here, I have few constraints on the vector $h$. If the first three elements are $a, b, c$, then the next three elements should be $pa^2, pb^2, pc^2$, where $p$ is a non-zero scaling factor. The last three elements should then be $2pab, 2pac, 2pbc$. How do I use such constraints on parameters using another parameter of an unknown vector? Could someone help me with this?
The solution $h = U^+y$ does not guarantee the desired structure of $h$, where $U^+$ is pseudoinverse of $U$. How to ensure that the solution has this structure and it best approximates the true noisy output y? Here the unknowns are a,b,c,p.
I have measurements of y and u from a system, where the output y is noisy. These measurements are coming from a system that should ideally follow the mathematical model that I described, i.e. at time step k, the output $y_k$ and input $u_k$ are related by: $y_k = au_k + bu_{k-1} + cu_{k-2} + p(au_k + bu_{k-1} + cu_{k-2} )^2$. I am writing this equation as a linear system of equation $y = Uh$ for $k = 1,...,N$ and I have to find $h$. Here you can assume $u$ is a random vector, which is used to construct matrix $U$ as given above and $y$ follows the mathematical model with prescribed $a,b,c$ and $p$. Now noise is added to y and I would like to find the prescribed $a, b, c$ and $p$ using the noisy measurement $y$ and matrix $U$.

What you actually have is a nonlinear system of equations in the unknowns $a$, $b$, $c$, and $p$ (if $p$ is not fixed.)

Yes, $p$ is not fixed and it is an unknown. Is this solvable?

It's a polynomial system of equations with 9 equations in 4 variables.  It should be quite easy to solve using Wolfram Mathematica or Maple or other symbolic computation software.

The solution for $h$ is $U^{-1}y$. But this solution might not have the constraint that I require in $h$. I have to find $h$ using $U$ and $y$, such that the vector $h$ has the said structure $h = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c & pa^2 & pb^2 & pc^2 & 2pab & 2pac & 2pbc \end{bmatrix}^T$.

How do I force this structure of $h$ in my solution step $h = U^{-1}y$?

$U^{-1}$ doesn't even exist if $N\neq 9$. Try to express your problem as a nonlinear system $F(a,b,c,p)=0\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and use a nonlinear solver.

I mean pseudoinverse of $U$.

If I expand the system: $y_k = au_k + bu_{k-1} + cu_{k-2} + pa^2u_k^2 + pb^2u_{k-1}^2 + pc^2u_{k-2}^2 + 2pabu_ku_{k-1} + 2pacu_ku_{k-2} + 2pbcu_{k-2}u_{k-1}$
for $k=1,...,N$.

Can you explain why you want to approach your system as if it were linear, despite it is not linear? Do you have some additional external constraint or limitation that somehow forces you to do so?

@Rigel The system I am working on is a Wiener system modelled with Volterra series of memory length 2 and nonlinearity order 2. I have measurements of u and y of length N, where noise in measurement is inevitable. But based on my prior knowledge about the Wiener system, the parameter vector $h$ has the structure I mentioned. Now, I would like to force this structure in the estimation of h. I do not have any other constraint or limitations

Missing from your setup is a designation of what kind of arithmetic (real, complex, or integer?) informs your problem's constraints.  Please edit into the post information of this kind.

I will use the notation $U_k$ and $U_{k,i}$ for rows and elements of matrix $U$, rather than small letter $u$, to avoid possible confusion with the $u_k$ notation in $y_k=au_k+bu_{k-1}+cu_{k−2}+pa^2u^2_k+pb^2u^2_{k−1}+pc^2u^2_{k−2}+2pabu_ku_{k−1}+2pacu_ku_{k−2}+2pbcu_{k−2}u_{k−1}$ for $k=1,\ldots,N$.
So the $k$th row of the system $y=Uh$ is $y_k=U_kh=aU_{k,1}+bU_{k,2}+cU_{k,3}+pa^2U_{k,4}+pb^2U_{k,5}+pc^2U_{k,6}+2pabU_{k,7}+2pacU_{k,8}+2pbcU_{k,9}$, where $U_k$ is the $k$th row of $U$ and $U_{k,i}$ is the $i$th element in the $k$th row of $U$.
Since the system $y=Uh$ is overdetermined and there are measurement errors in $y_k$ and $U_{k,i}, k=1,\ldots,N, i=1,\ldots,9$, you can think of the problem of determining $\beta=[a,b,c,p]$ as a fitting problem in which you seek a value of $\beta$ that makes $Uh$ as close as possible to $y$, in some sense. A common approach is nonlinear least squares, where the objective is to minimize the sum of squares of the residuals:
$\min_\beta \sum_{k=1}^N r_k^2$
where $r_k=y_k-U_kh$. The $N$-vector $r$ is the residual vector.
You can use almost any nonlinear optimization algorithm to solve a nonlinear least squares problem, but the Levenberg-Marquardt (LM) algorithm is specifically designed to solve this problem. You usually have to give an optimization algorithm an initial guess for the value of $\beta$. If your guess is not sufficiently close to the optimal value, then the algorithm may fail to find a solution. LM can often find a solution even if you make a bad initial guess.
MATLAB has an LM implementation. So does Scipy. The "Numerical Recipes" books have an LM algorithm. If you search, you can probably find source code for any language you prefer.

Thank you for your solution. Here, $y_k = au_k + bu_{k-1} + cu_{k−2} + pa^2u^2_k + pb^2u^2_{k−1} + pc^2u^2_{k−2} + 2pabu_ku_{k−1} + 2pacu_ku_{k−2} + 2pbcu_{k−2}u_{k−1}$ for $k=1,\ldots,N$, $u$ is a vector of length $N$ and $u_k$ is the $k$-th sample of $u$. So, $u_{k-1}$ is the ${k-1}$-th sample of $u$, $u_{k-1}^2$ is the square of ${k-1}$-th sample of $u$ and $u_ku_{k-1}$ is the product of $k$ and ${k-1}$-th samples of u.

So here $u_k$ is a measurement that is used to calculate the value of some of the elements in rows $k$, $k+1$, and $k+2$ of $U$; $u_k$ is not to be confused (as I was) with one possible notation for elements of $U$.

Yes, now for this case, I would like to know if there is a possibility to find h with the said structure.

Yes, using least squares to find $h$ might work.  Luckily, the solution method I proposed is unchanged, in spite of my misunderstanding.  I edited the notation in my answer above so I hopefully won’t lead anyone astray about the meaning of $u$.

I edited my question for some more clarity. The NL LS solution for $h$ will not give me the structure that I desire. Please check my question and help, if you have time. Thank you for the support

The answer above does not find coordinates of $h$, it finds $a$, $b$, $c$, and $p$ using nonlinear least squares. Once these values are obtained, they can be used to form $h$ which has the correct structure since it was explicitly used to construct the optimization problem. Again, the problem is not linear in the independent variables so you should not consider linear techniques such as pseudoinverses
